# Retrieve Selected Option Value From HTML DropDownList

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I've a `DropDownList` where user has to select options and save it to database. I am using the following with `AngularJs`:

```
 <select>
    <option>----Please Select Sub-Category----</option>
    <option ng-repeat="m in Categories" value="{{ m.CategoryId }}" ng-model="saveProducts.CategoryId">{{ m.Category }}</option>
 </select>
```

I can show the values in the above `DropDownList` but stuck to retrieve the value from the selected and pass it to the scope. I've tried even this, a silly one:

```
 <select>
    <option>----Please Select Sub-Category----</option>
    <option ng-repeat="m in Categories" value="{{ m.CategoryId }}" ng-model="m.CategoryId">{{ m.Category }}</option>
 </select>
```

But that will not work. `saveProducts` is the object (scope) where I am passing values but is there any easy way where I can pass option value with the above procedure?

Here what I am doing to save data in database and it works fine except the option value, it's unable to retrieve values with the above:

```
productApp.controller('addProductController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.addData = function () {

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Product/AddProductsToDb',
            data: $scope.saveProducts
        }).success(function () {
            $scope.saveProducts = null;

        }).error(function () {
            alert('Failed');
        });
    }
});
```

This is the output I have and just want to pass the option value from it:

[image: Sample_Image]

**Update 1** - This is what I've tried but I can show the value in the alert method using as follows:

```
<select ng-model="saveProducts.ParentId"
        ng-options="m.Category for m in Categories track by m.CategoryId">
      <option value="">----Please Select Sub-Category----</option>
</select>
```

**AngularJs Controller**:

```
productApp.controller('addProductController', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.addData = function () {
        angular.forEach($scope.saveProducts, function (model, index) {
            $scope.saveProducts.ParentId = (model.CategoryId);
        });

        alert($scope.saveProducts.ParentId);

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Product/AddProductsToDb',
            data: $scope.saveProducts
        }).success(function () {
            $scope.saveProducts = null;

        }).error(function () {
            alert('Failed');
        });
     }
});
```

**Note**: It saves **TextBox** input value but stuck with **DropDownList**. Unable to retrieve select option value and save it to database.

Comment: Where are you getting `Categories` array which you are using for your ng-repeat ?

Comment: Again, when I try this - **alert($scope.saveProducts.ParentId)**, it returns **[Object Object]** @Shyju.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a property to store the selected option. You can use `ng-options` to render the dropdown.

```
<select ng-model="selectedCategory"
        ng-options="option.Category for option in Categories track by option.CategoryId ">
    <option value="">Select Option</option>
</select>
```

Now your select element's ng-model is set to `selectedCategory`. So in your add method you can access that and use that for saving.

```
$scope.addData = function () {
    console.log($scope.selectedCategory);
    //to do : use selectedCategory 
}
```

Comment: OK @Shyju. I'll try that. I've already a scope called `saveProducts` that passes values to database and how can I pass or integrate the above with the `SaveProducts`?

Comment: what is `saveProducts` ?

Comment: I've tried the code @Shyju but it doesn't get the value and saves null in the database. This is what I've done - **<select ng-model="saveProducts.SubCategory" ng-options="m.Category for m in Categories track by m.CategoryId"><option value="">----Please Select Sub-Category----</option></select>**. Then I iterated it with a loop - **angular.forEach($scope.saveProducts, function (model, index) { $scope.saveProducts.SubCategory = (model.CategoryId); });**. I can retrieve the values but again it saves null value in the database. See my updated post.

Comment: As i explained in the code, the ng-model of the SELECT is set to `selectedCategory`. So when user changes the option, the value of this will be updated. Now when `addData` method is called, all you have to do is send the data as need to your server. You have the selected value in `$scope.selectedCategory` use that to save as needed

Comment: I've used this `alert($scope.selectedCategory);` @Shyju and it returns **[Object Object]**. In database, it shows null value.

Comment: you have to use that objects.Id value and send that to your server code where you save the Id value to the corresponding column in the database. There is no such magic where you fix one problem and all other problems are resolved. My answer is to give you the object which has the selected option in the addData method. Use the value from that and save as needed.

Comment: I made it work @Shyju and missed a small thing. Thanks a lot and could you please up-vote my post? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use ngOptions. Depending on the structure of your `Categories` data, you could do something like:

```
<select ng-options="m as m.yourProperty for m in Categories" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

Then, in Angular...

```
$scope.selected = $scope.Categories[0];
```

Read [the ngOptions documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) to tweak according to your needs.